# how to access an exported json object in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Dopey question.  I have an object from a library and I want to access it but I just don't get it. Here is the exported object:

```js
exports.listAccounts = function(successCallback,errorCallback)
{

    var actionDescriptor = {
            method : "GET",
            module : "accounts",
            action : "accountlist",
            useJSON: true,
    };
    
    this._run(actionDescriptor,{},successCallback,errorCallback);
};
```

Now I want to access the account list in code at etListAccounts:

```js
//user sends confirmation code and we get acesss token
app.get('/users/sendcode', function (req, res) {
    console.log('verification CODE is '+req.query.vCode);
//end get verification code
    et.getAccessToken(req.query.vCode,
      function() {
      console.log('thread entered getAccessToken function')
        et.listAccounts(
            function(){console.log('account list success')},
            function(error) {
                console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                            "to retrieve account list: " +
                             error);
      });
    //   console.log(accountlist[0]);  
      },

      function(error) {
        console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                    "to exchange request token for access token: " +
                    error);
      }
    );
})
```

I've tried this:

```js
et.listAccounts(
                function(accountList){console.log('account list success')},
                function(error) {
                    console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                                "to retrieve account list: " +
                                 error);
          });
```

And I've tried this:

```js
et.listAccounts(
                function(){accountList},
                function(error) {
                    console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                                "to retrieve account list: " +
                                 error);
          });
```

And I've tried this:

```js
accountList - et.listAccounts(
                function(){console.log('account list success')},
                function(error) {
                    console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                                "to retrieve account list: " +
                                 error);
          });
```

This is a nice simple question and I feel foolish for asking it but lots of people can answer it and lots of beginners will find it useful.

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work.

            et.listAccounts(
                function(accountList){console.log('account list success')},
                function(error) {
                    console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                                "to retrieve account list: " +
                                 error);
          });

Comment: and this:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

            et.listAccounts(
                function(){accountList},
                function(error) {
                    console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                                "to retrieve account list: " +
                                 error);
          });


<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: And this:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

            accountList = et.listAccounts(
                function(){console.log('account list success')},
                function(error) {
                    console.log("Error encountered while attempting " +
                                "to retrieve account list: " +
                                 error);
          });


<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: What is "it doesn't work" do you mean? Please elaborate more on it like getting error on console or something.

Comment: The way the second snippet is written above, everything works but console messages only go so far.  Now I need the real data.  It's in a json file called accountlist. etListAccounts should return it but how do I get it?  Set a variable equal to etListAccounts?  Replace my console.log instruction with a variable name?  Insert a variable name into the arguments list?

Comment: Ok so one of your questions is **how to import an object from an other JSON file in JavaScript**, right?

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet you shared with us, it appears that you are not importing the module. Please read the documentation here:

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module

`var imported = require('nameOfModule');`

Comment: The first snippet is in a library. The second is in app.js.  The second snipped runs just find and the console message reports success.  Console message reports rest endpoint, too. .../rest/accountlist.json.  But how do I access that json file?  Successcallback should contain it, right?